# QMediaPlayer is unable to play song on Window

Tags: c++, qt

Hello Techie's I am working on Qt `QMediaPlayer` and trying to play song through my local file but i don't know where I am getting wrong I am unable to play song on Window but the same code is working fine in Mac but not on window.
For all kind helps Thanks in advance.

I had tried this

```
player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("<path to file>/test.mp3"));
```

and this as well

```
player->setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl::fromLocalFile("<path to file>/test.mp3")));
```

Here's my complete code snippet:

```
QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer();
player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("<path to file>/test.mp3"));
player->setVolume(100);
player->play();
qDebug() << player->errorString();
```

No error listed, so its difficult to identify where I am getting wrong.

Comment: Have you a message on the standard output ?

Comment: No I got no error message and also no song playing but when i play this song on some media player outside it plays well.

Comment: Can you show more code please ? Because `play()` is not blocking so maybe you leave your program just after starting your song

Comment: See below are the mention steps which I have followed to perform the whole operation:
1) Downloaded the songs from the server
2) Encrypted/Decrypted it using openssl
3) After decryption I store the content in qbytearray variable
4) Using QBuffer I have set the media of the QMediaplayer
5) And then plays the media, It works for most of the songs

But some of the songs are not played, I didn't even get any errors. The things I get to know is like IsAudioAvailable and isSeekable method returns false.
On next comment I am adding the code.

Comment: void PlayerAction::SetMedia()
{
    auto buffer = GetSongData();

    player->setMedia(QMediaContent(),buffer);
    Play();
//    free(buffer);
}

QBuffer *PlayerAction::GetSongData()
{
    QString mp3FilePath = MUSIC_PATH+info.fileName;
    Cipher cipher;
    QByteArray encryptedData = cipher.readFile(mp3FilePath);  
    auto decryptedFile  = cipher.decryptAES(pass.toLatin1(),encryptedData);

    QBuffer *buffer = new QBuffer(this);
    buffer->setData(decryptedFile);
    buffer->open(QFile::ReadOnly);

    return buffer;
}

Comment: if it is dependent on the file, it might be because of the encoding on MP3, as far as I know MP3 can contain different codecs, it's not always the same.

Comment: check this out: https://www.ulduzsoft.com/2016/03/usability-of-qt5-qmediaplayer-for-multimedia-applications/

Answer (score -1):

Have you try some path format, i had a similar experience with QMediaPlayer and i had to use path format like this `some\\path\\exemple.mp3` or like this `some//path//exemple.mp3` i don't remember exactly.

Maybe check [QMediaPlayer exemple](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-multimediawidgets-player-example.html) and try to run the exemple to check if is codec problem or a code problem.

Comment: I am able to play song on other player and its works absolutely fine and when I Pass URL instead of path of my PC then I am able to play the song easily, but by my system path I am unable to play song

Comment: ok, so is a Path error if you can play song with URL, have you tried the different path format that i gave you ?

Comment: Yes I had tried all the possible path format and that you gave also none of them works for me I am really stuck with this problem of mine. I had check the codec of both the playing and non playing song both have the same codec i.e MPEG Audio layer 1/2(mpga)